# keras predicting classes method

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

So, I have this little project going on about predicting the nba 2019 champion but it seems that my code is not clear enough to make keras understand what I want. I have passed a list of past champions on my dataset and made it the output class to get the current champion.

I'm using a dataset for teams stats from 2014 to 2018 regular seasons and I'm assuming that I should have the 2019 stats to do it. I have made my dataset very well encoded for my NN to understand by providing one hot encoding in every feature I think it's useful.

```py
x = pd.concat([df.drop(['Unnamed: 0','Team','Game','Date','Opponent','LastSeasonChamp'], axis = 1), df_ohc], axis = 1)
y = df['LastSeasonChamp']

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.35)

x_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train.values, axis = 1)
x_test = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_test.values, axis = 1)

n_classes = 30

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(x_train.shape[1], input_shape = (x_train.shape[0],x_train.shape[1]), activation = tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(np.mean([x_train.shape[1], n_classes], dtype = int), activation = tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_classes, activation = tf.nn.softmax))

model.compile(optimizer = 'adagrad' , loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train.values, epochs = 3)

model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
model.save('nba_champ_2019')
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('nba_champ_2019')
pred = new_model.predict(x_test)
y_pred = to_categorical(pred)
```

So, I could expect my y_pred to be a column with 0 and 1 and but all I get is a column full of 1.

Answer (score 0):

The `to_categorical` function is used to convert a list of class IDs to an one-hot matrix. You don't need it here. You should get the output you expect by removing in this case.